# Expression of Logical Connectives of Sets with Set-Builder Notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I require some guidance with the following question:

> Consider the following subsets of all integers.
>   $$\begin{align*}
> A&=\{2n+1\mid n\text{ is an element of all integers}\}\\
> B&=\{3n\mid n\text{ is an element of all integers}\}\\
> C&=\{3n+2\mid n\text{ is an element of all integers}\}
> \end{align*}$$
>   Find each of the following sets, and express it in set-builder notation.
>
> 1. $A-B$.
> 2. $B\cap C$.
> 3. $C\cap B^c$

Answer (score 1):

Can you describe in words what $A-B$, $B\cap C$, and $C\cap(B^c)$ are?

For example, for an integer to be in $B$, it must be a multiple of $3$. To be in $C$, it must be an even number plus $2$ (that is, it must be an even number). So to be in $B\cap C$, it must be *both* even and a multiple of $3$. Can you describe what numbers are both even and multiples of $3$? If so, then you can put that description into the "set-builder notation".

So, start by figuring out what is in each of the three sets (with words). We can then go on from there.